# Удалить все четные столбцы из динамической матрицы

Tags: c++, циклы, матрицы, динамические-массивы

есть задание :

> Удалить все четные столбцы из динамической матрицы .

Вот что я сделал :

```
void Matrix()
{
    system("CLS");
 
    int string = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
 
    cout << "Enter the number of lines:";
    cin >> string;
    cout << "Enter the nuber of columns:";
    cin >> column;
 
    int** matrix = new int* [string];
    for (i = 0; i < string; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
            matrix[i] = new int[column];
 
    cout << "Matrix view after filling:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < string; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        {
            matrix[i][j] = ((rand() % 10));
            cout << setw(2) << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    cout << "Matrix view after removing all even columns:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < string; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j+2) 
        {
            matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j+1];
        }
        column--;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < string; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        {
            cout << setw(2) << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Что сделал не так ?
Заранее очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простите, проще написать заново...

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
 
    cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter the nuber of columns: ";
    cin >> cols;
 
    int** matrix = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[cols];
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
 
    cout << "Matrix view after filling:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            cout << setw(2) << matrix[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
    {
        if (i%2 == 1)
            for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
                matrix[j][(i-1)/2] = matrix[j][i];
    }

    cols = cols/2;

    cout << "Matrix view after removing all even columns:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            cout << setw(2) << matrix[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Да, так как вы не уточнили, что такое "*четные столбцы*" - под четными столбцами я понимаю столбцы с четными индексами.

Comment: Спасибо большое , разобрался .